# When will SIP shutdown the computer to prevent overheating?

Tags: high-sierra, gpu, cpu, temperature, sip

I have a MacBook Pro Early 2015 running macOS High Sierra. I've managed to get it to pretty high temperatures for both the CPU and the GPU. I've managed to get them to at least 100ºC and the computer didn't shutdown.

At what temperature will SIP(System Integrity Protection) shutdown the computer to prevent thermal damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/HT204899) has nothing to do with controlling what happens if the CPU breaches it thermal limit.

> System Integrity Protection is a security technology in OS X El Capitan and later that's designed to help prevent potentially malicious software from modifying protected files and folders on your Mac. System Integrity protection restricts the [root user account](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204012) and limits the actions that the root user can perform on protected parts of the Mac operating system.

---

All the CPU's used in the Early 2015 MacBook Pro, Intel Core i5 or Core i7 ([5257U](https://ark.intel.com/products/84985/Intel-Core-i5-5257U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), [5287U](https://ark.intel.com/products/84988/Intel-Core-i5-5287U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz), [5557U](https://ark.intel.com/products/84993/Intel-Core-i7-5557U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz)) have a 105℃ <sup>T</sup>JUNCTION* rating.

- **<sup>*</sup>** Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.

While 100℃ is high and getting close to the limit, it hasn't breached the limit yet.

Comment: You are correct about SIP, but I’d like to add that most newer computers don’t actually shut down at their Tjunction rating. Instead, they downclock the CPU/GPU to lower the temperature.

Comment: @IronCraftMan, my answer is obviously directed at the OP's misunderstanding that SIP has anything to do with controlling the thermal dynamics of the hardware and I've included the temperature info just to show that while 100℃ is high and getting close to the limit, it hasn't breached the limit yet. I intensionally did not include any info about how regulating the temperature takes place or what happens at 105℃ or higher because SIP will never shutdown the computer to prevent overheating and is explicitly what was asked in the OP.